# No sound on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10 and I lost the sound on my laptop. There was sound in the beginning, but after another restart, it was gone. All media players won't play music, no sound from movies or youtube, sound test is negative however the system detects that there is a "built-in audio" device. There is no output on the speakers and no input from the microphone is detected. How can I fix this problem?